# Create a pivot table using two columns treating them as a group

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe, crosstab

I have seen plenty of answers that address replicating R's dcast functionality using a single column as the index but I am having a hard time replicating a dcast where you are combining columns to group them and then pivoting.  I keep running into issues when I try to use pivot_table or crosstab where I end up with either dropped columns or mixed up names.

I have a DataFrame that looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['History', 'History', 'English','Math','Gym', 'Gym'], 
                   'first': ['John','Mary','John', 'Charles', 'John', 'Charles'], 
                   'last': ['Smith', 'Jones', 'Smith', 'Right', 'Smith', 'Right'], 
                   'grade': ['1','2','1','3', np.nan, np.nan] })
```

```
     class    first   last grade
0  History     John  Smith     1
1  History     Mary  Jones     2
2  English     John  Smith     1
3     Math  Charles  Right     3
4      Gym     John  Smith   NaN
5      Gym  Charles  Right   NaN
```

when I try to create a pivot table grouping first and last, it creates a table but does not group the names together.  It creates row using all combinations of the first and last:

```
df2 = df.pivot_table(index=['first', 'last'], 
                     columns=['class'], 
                     aggfunc={'grade': max}, 
                     dropna=False).fillna(0)
```

```
                grade
class         English Gym History Math
first   last
Charles Jones       0   0       0    0
        Right       0   0       0    3
        Smith       0   0       0    0
John    Jones       0   0       0    0
        Right       0   0       0    0
        Smith       1   0       1    0
Mary    Jones       0   0       2    0
        Right       0   0       0    0
        Smith       0   0       0    0
```

I am trying to replicate the behavior of R's dcast:

```
df2 <- dcast.data.table(df,first + last  ~ class, value.var ='grade')
```

```
   first   last     English  Gym       History Math
1: Charles Right    <NA>     <NA>      <NA>    3
2:    John Smith    1        <NA>      1       <NA>
3:    Mary Jones    <NA>     <NA>      2       <NA>
```

I realize if I set dropna=True it will just remove the extra rows but it will also remove the columns with NaNs in it and I do not want that.  I need to preserve the columns.

Comment: I see this was closed due as a duplicate but none of those deal with this particular problem I am working with.  I did not see any of them trying to use two columns as a group when creating a pivot table.

Comment: ```pd.crosstab(columns=df['class'],index=[df["first"],df["last"]], values = df['grade'], aggfunc={max})```

Comment: "If you don't think your question is a duplicate, then [edit] your question to clarify how it's different and why none of those other answers apply." Don't let the downvotes disappoint you. They are not directed at you, but simply are users expressing their opinion that this should not be asked as there are multiple duplicates. If you edit and clarify as I suggested, I will be open to reopening the question and will be the first to upvote. Cheers.

Comment: The problem with the crosstab example you posted is it drops the Gym column unless you specify dropna=False and then you end up with the mixed up names again.

Answer (score 1):

How about `unstack`:

```
df.set_index(['first', 'last', 'class']).unstack() \
  .droplevel(0, axis=1) \
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1) \
  .reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `NaN` with a specified number like `-999`, use the `crosstab` function, and later replace `-999` with `NaN`. See below;

```py
df1 = df.fillna(-999)

df2 = pd.crosstab(columns=df1['class'], index=[df1["first"],df1["last"]], 
                  values = df1['grade'], aggfunc={max})
df2[df2 == -999] = np.nan
```

```
                  max                    
class         English   Gym History  Math
first   last                             
Charles Right    None   NaN    None     3
John    Smith       1   NaN       1  None
Mary    Jones    None  None       2  None
```